# Pygame.image.load() not working with PyInstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

```
img_l = pygame.image.load("img.png")
screen.blit(img_l)
```

With Python Interpreter it works fine, image loads and `main.py` runs without problems, but when I make it into one file `.exe` with Pyinstaller, `.exe` crashes.

I've tried few `.spec` modifications, but few I've managed to find don't seem to help.

Any ideas sincerely appreciated.

**EDIT: got it working with:**

```
img_l = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('img.png'))
screen.blit(img_l, (0, 0))
```

Now it works as it should after going through PyInstaller :)

Comment: Are you getting an exception traceback when your program crashes? It's hard to diagnose a problem with no information. My first guess would be that `img.png` can't be loaded because it's not in the place your program expects it.

Comment: All I get `fatal error: main returned -1`. I've tried adding `img.png` to same place as `.exe`, not working. From what you said I just now got idea that maybe `img.png` needs to be in same place as PyInstaller... gonna test EDIT: nope.

Comment: It might be worth adding a line to print out the current working directory. That way you can see specifically where the application is looking for the file.

`import os;
print os.getcwd();`

Comment: @jacobPersi  I get invalid syntax error `import os; print os.getcwd();`. Not sure if I am using that right. Trying to look it up and see what I am doing wrong, sorry I am still pretty new to Python.

Comment: If you're using Python 3 you'll have to wrap the print statement in parentheses.

I.e
import os;
print(os.getcwd());

Comment: I got it working! Wohoo! :) it was because I was sloppy with defining where to load image from. Thanks for help guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it working with:

```
img_l = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('img.png'))
screen.blit(img_l, (0, 0))
```

Now it works as it should after going through PyInstaller :)

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else who is having the same problem and has tried @Esa's answer, you may notice that it sometimes does not work when run outside the directory. This is caused by Pyinstaller still trying to find the relative path and not using the included files instead. This can be fixed by finding the correct path inside your code before loading files:

```
if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
    Path = sys._MEIPASS              #This is for when the program is frozen
else:
    Path = os.path.dirname(__file__) #This is when the program normally runs
```

This finds the actual path of your file and must be done for every file, e.g:

```
pygame.image.load(os.path.join(Path, 'Path\\to_file\\from_root'))
```

`sys._MEIPASS` is the key as it will find the path when the program is frozen as when a program is frozen, it's files are stored somewhere else.

When you generate the .exe file a .spec file will also be created with the root directory. In there you will need to edit this as follows:

1. You should see a file structure similar to the one below
2. Notice how `datas` is equal to `None`. You will have to edit this.

This is the .spec file in the root directory currently:

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None

#you will have to add things here later

a = Analysis(['file.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\path\\to\\root\\folder'],
             binaries=None,
             datas=None,
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='game_file',
          debug=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True , icon='icon_file.ico')
```

Now what we do is we add all our files: Place this `added_files` below `block_cipher` but above `Analysis()`, e.g:

```
added_files = [
              ('file1.png', '.')        #The '.' represents root folder
              ('file2.png', '\\folder') #loads file2.png from root\folder
              ]
```

Now inside of `Analysis()` we change the `None` after `datas` to `added_files`. You will also notice that there are the main different options for your final file. You can edit these here if you want but you cannot change the "onefile" option, this is made when the .spec file is created.

Finally to make this new exe file, go to your root folder in cmd and type this:

```
pyinstaller "PY_FILE_NAME.spec"
```

The final exe, whether in a folder or not should be in root\dist\Executable_name.exe or root\dist\Executable_name\Executable_name.exe

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same problem. For some reason the working directory is not set properly for the --onefile packaged executable. I managed to resolve it by using the following piece of code at the beginning of my program.
This is similar to the above proposed solutions but I find it slightly more elegant :) 
It basically forces the working directory to the temporary extracted directory in case we are running as a single executable.

```
import sys
import os
if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
    os.chdir(sys._MEIPASS)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I'm very very new to programming.
I'm getting a similar (the same?) error when I try to run my `.exe`
It says:

```
pygame.error: Couldn't open walkr1.png
```

I tried the fix that you used, but then got the error:

```
pygame.error: Can't seek in this data source
```

The image files are in a folder in the folder with the main `.py` file. I've tried moving the files to the same folder but that didn't work. I've also tried adding the data files to the `.spec` file, but that doesn't seem to work either...
Was wondering if you could help? 
Sorry, I know these are probably all very dumb questions.